# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db_java-4.2 in java.library.path

Tags: berkeley-db, loadlibrary, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm trying to access a Berkeley DB database file (say Test.db) from the java code and then want to read all the  pairs from it. I'm using the `com.sleepycat.db.*` and `com.sleepycat.bdb.*` packages ( *NOTE: Not Oracle Berkeley DB JE* )to do this task. For the implementation, I did exactly as described in this [BerkeleyDB Java API Tutorial](http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/doc/BerkeleyDB/ref/bdb_tut/intro.html)

So, when I run this project from eclipse I got this error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db_java-4.2 in java.library.path`

and from the stack trace, source for this exception occured from this line

```
env = new DbEnv(0);
```

I tried to set it from the java command

`$java -D<name>=<value>`

but still it didn't work.

My goal is to **export this project into a jar file and use it to read BDBs anywhere** . Anyone who knows how to get out of this, I appreciate your help. It would be great if I can be redirected to any working tutorial for accessing Berkeley DBs from java code too. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: After a lot of work, I found out that the Sleepycat API that I'm working on is using native libraries that are written in C/C++ through the JNI. Berkeley DB that is installed on my PC didn't have the shared object file db_java-4.2 (to be accurate, file name is libdb_java-4.2) which means that this BDB is not configured for java APIs.

So, the solution is to start the installation of BDB from scratch again by enabling the java configuration.

Comment: please explain a bit better how to fix this issue

Comment: Use the `--enable-java` flag to build with Java support. This builds Java support for both Berkeley DB and Berkeley DB XML

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Like kK_Pulla mentioned, the sleepycat API using native libraries written in C/C++ through the Java Native Interface. So making Sleepycat API calls means the java code is ultimately going to call compiled C/C++ code.

If you are getting the "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db_java-4.2 in java.library.path" error then it is likely that, at least it was in my case, you have not included the relevant native libraries in your project.

I would describe what I did to fix it in my case. Firstly let me describe my environment.

1. IntelliJ maven Java project on a linux machine.
2. Built Berkeley DB version 18.1.40.
3. The Berkeley build included the --enable-java switch in the configuration phase.
4. I included the db.jar (found in the build_unix directory) as a module dependency through the Intellij menus File> Project Structure. I selected Modules under Project settings on the left pane and then under the dependencies tab I added the db.jar file as a dependency.

This was the state of my project before I encountered the UnsatisfiedLinkError. To fix that I added the native libraries (found in the unix_build/.libs directory) to the project. You can do this by selecting the File menu> then Project Structure. On the left pane under project settings select Libraries and then click the + sign on the right pane to add the directory for the native libs.

This fixed my problem.